# Error while installing package from github in R. Error in dyn.load

Tags: r, recommendation-engine, lapack

I am trying to install the recommenderlabrats package from github to my SUSE Linux R-Server, using the straight forward:

```
devtools::install_github("sanealytics/recommenderlabrats")
```

However I do get an error message which I can't get wrap my head around.

```
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/home/ruser/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.2/recommenderlabrats/libs/recommenderlabrats.so':
  /home/ruser/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.2/recommenderlabrats/libs/recommenderlabrats.so: undefined symbol: dgels_
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
```

I guess it boils down to

```
undefined symbol: dgels_
```

After some stackoverflow- and google-search, I think it has something to do with Rcpp. I have version 0.12.0 installed. 
I tried to contact the author but didn't receive any feedback. 
I do get a similar error on my local windows machine.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You probably need `liblapack-dev`

Comment: `dgels` is part of the lapack that ships with R (as well as of every full installation).  This sounds more like bad package build instructions missing a `-llapack`.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel bad package build instructions on two completely different machines? I mean, those are not the first R systems I ever build, but the first two I tried this specific github repo.

Would you suggest re-install of R?

Comment: I have no idea. It is a package I do not use (recommenderlabrats) installed with a method I do not particularly like (install_github).  But this is not an Rcpp issue as best as I can tell so I am going to remove that tag.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same issue.
According to @DirkEddelbuettel's comment, I added

```
Sys.setenv("PKG_LIBS" = "-llapack")
```

Then the installation worked.

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of the package.. Someone emailed me this error recently so looked through it I found this post.. fixed... and thanks for using the package and testing recommendation algorithms. Let me know how I can help. It's always great to see other folks researching personalization.

Feel free to contribute or open an issue in github and I will respond prompty. Apologies to Daniel who did report it earlier but I could explore at that time.