# Recommenderlab running into memory issues

Tags: r, recommendation-engine

I am trying to compare some recommender algorithms against each other but am running into some memory issues. The dataset that i am using is https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By5yrncwiz_VZUpiak5Hc2l3dkE

Following is my code:

```
library(recommenderlab)
library(Matrix)

Amazon <- read.csv(Path to Reviews.csv, header = TRUE, 
               col.names = c("ID","ProductId","UserId","HelpfulnessNumerator","HelpfulnessDenominator","Score",
                             "Time","Summary","Text"),
               colClasses = c("NULL","character","character","NULL","NULL","integer","NULL","NULL","NULL"))

Amazon <- Amazon[,c("UserId","ProductId","Score")]

Amazon <- Amazon[!duplicated(Amazon[1:2]),] ## To get unique values

scheme <- evaluationScheme(r, method = "split", train = .7,
                       k = 1, given = 1 ,goodRating = 4)

algorithms <- list(
"user-based CF" = list(name="UBCF", param=list(normalize = "Z-score",
                                             method="Cosine",
                                             nn=50, minRating=3)),
"item-based CF" = list(name="IBCF", param=list(normalize = "Z-score"
))

)

results <- evaluate(scheme, algorithms, n=c(1, 3, 5))
```

I get the following errors :

```
UBCF run fold/sample [model time/prediction time]
 1  Timing stopped at: 1.88 0 1.87 
Error in asMethod(object) : 
Cholmod error 'problem too large' at file ../Core/cholmod_dense.c, line 105
IBCF run fold/sample [model time/prediction time]
 1  Timing stopped at: 4.93 0.02 4.95 
Error in asMethod(object) : 
Cholmod error 'problem too large' at file ../Core/cholmod_dense.c, line 105
Warning message:
In .local(x, method, ...) : 
Recommender 'user-based CF' has failed and has been removed from the results!
Recommender 'item-based CF' has failed and has been removed from the results!
```

I tried to use recommenderlabrats package which i thought would solve this problem but could not install it.   https://github.com/sanealytics/recommenderlabrats

It gave me some errors which i am not bale to make sense of:

c:/rbuildtools/3.3/gcc-4.6.3/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64- mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -llapack
 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Then i came to this link for solving the recommenderlabrats problem but it did not work for me 
[Error while installing package from github in R. Error in dyn.load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32069122/error-while-installing-package-from-github-in-r-error-in-dyn-load)

Any help on how to get around the memory issue is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I am the author of recommenderlabrats. Try to install now, it should be fixed. Then use RSVD/ALS to solve. Your matrix is too big even when it's sparse for your computer.

Also, it might be a good idea to experiment with a smaller sample before spending on an AWS memory instance.